# Create promises on queries inside a for loop

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to write a Node.js code that does the below.

1. Connect to a Salesforce instance.
2. Get the past 7 days, and loop through them.
3. Run 2 queries inside them and push the result to an Array.
4. Display the value in another function.

Here is my JS code.

```
var jsforce = require("jsforce");
var moment = require('moment');

function connectToEP() {
    var main_Obj = {};
    var response_Obj = {};
    var pastSevenDaysArray = [];
    var conn = new jsforce.Connection();
    var beforeSevenDays = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var today = moment().startOf('day');
    var i = 0;


    conn.login("myUid", "myPwd").then(() => {
        console.log("Connected To Dashboard");
        for (var m = moment(beforeSevenDays); m.diff(today, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
            conn.query("SELECT SUM(Total_ETA_of_all_tasks__c), SUM(Total_ETA__C) from Daily_Update__c where DAY_ONLY(createddate)= " + m.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).then(() => {
                console.log("B1");
                var z = response_Obj.aggrRes;
                response_Obj.aggrRes = res;
                pastSevenDaysArray.push({ z: res });
                console.log("B1 Exit");

            }).then(() => {
                conn.query("SELECT count(Id), Task_Type__c FROM Daily_Task__c where DAY_ONLY(createddate) = " + m.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " group by Task_Type__c").then(() => {
                    console.log("B2");

                    var z = response_Obj.aggrRes;
                    response_Obj.aggrRes = res;
                    pastSevenDaysArray.push({ z: res });
                    console.log("B2 Exit");

                })
            })
        }
        return Promise.resolve(pastSevenDaysArray);
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(typeof data);
        updateMessage(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(typeof data);
    });

}
function updateMessage(message) {
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    console.log(message);
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
}
function socketNotificationReceived() {
    console.log("socket salesforce rec");
    connectToEP();
}

socketNotificationReceived();
```

when I run this code, the output that I get is.

```
socket salesforce rec
Connected To Dashboard
object
XXXXXXXXXXXX
[]
XXXXXXXXXXXX
object
B1
B1
B1
B1
B1
B1
B1
B1
```

I'm very new to this js platform, unable to get the promises concepts :(.  please let me know on were am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

An explanation of what's going is very helpful in my future projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I always do when I get confused is to *decompose*.  Build the pieces one by one, and make sure each works.  Trying to understand your code, I get something like this...

A function each for logging in, getting a "task sum" from the db and getting a "task count" from the db.  (Task sum/count is what I guessed the queries were up to.  Rename as you see fit).

```
var jsforce = require("jsforce");
var moment = require('moment');

function login(conn) {
    return conn.login("myUid", "myPwd");
}

function queryTaskSumForDay(conn, m) {
    return conn.query("SELECT SUM(Total_ETA_of_all_tasks__c), SUM(Total_ETA__C) from Daily_Update__c where DAY_ONLY(createddate)= " + m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

function queryTaskCountForDay(conn, m) {
    return conn.query("SELECT count(Id), Task_Type__c FROM Daily_Task__c where DAY_ONLY(createddate) = " + m.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " group by Task_Type__c");
}
```

With those working, it should be easy to get a sum and a count for a given day.  Rather than returning these in an array (containing two objects that each have a "z" property as your code did), I opted for the simpler single object that has a sum and count property.  You may need to change this to suit your design.  Notice the use of `Promise.all()` to resolve two promises together...

```
function sumAndCountForDay(conn, m) {
    let sum = queryTaskSumForDay(conn, m);
    let count = queryTaskCountForDay(conn, m);
    return Promise.all([sum, count]).then(results => {
        return { sum: results[0], count: results[1] };
    });
}
```

With that working, it should be easy to get an array of sum-count objects for a period of seven days using your moment logic and the `Promise.all()` idea...

```
function sumAndCountForPriorWeek(conn) {
    let promises = [];
    let beforeSevenDays = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let today = moment().startOf('day');
    for (let m = moment(beforeSevenDays); m.diff(today, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
        promises.push(sumAndCountForDay(conn, m));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

With that working (notice the pattern here?), your OP function is tiny and nearly fully tested because we tested all of it's parts...

```
function connectToEP() {
    let conn = new jsforce.Connection();
    return login(conn).then(() => {
        return sumAndCountForPriorWeek(conn)
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        return result;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        return error;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your general structure should be something like this. The biggest issue is not returning promises when you need to. A "for loop" of promises is a little difficult to step into, but if you can do them in parallel then the easiest thing to do is `Promise.all` If you need to aggregate the data before you can perform the next query then you need to do multiple `Promise.all().then()`'s.   The reason you get an empty array [] is because your for loop creates the promises but doesn't wait until they finish.

```
var jsforce = require("jsforce");
var moment = require('moment');

function connectToEP() {
  // connectToEP now returns a promise  
  return conn.login("myUid", "myPwd").then(() => {
        console.log("Connected To Dashboard");
        let myQueries = [];
        for (start ; condition ; incrementer) {
            myQueries.push( // Add all these query promises to the parallel queue
                conn.query(someQuery)
                    .then((res) => {
                        return res;
                    })
                    .then((res) => {
                        return conn.query(someQuery).then((res) => {
                            return someData;
                        })
                    })
            )
        }
        return Promise.all(myQueries); // Waits for all queries to finish...
    }).then((allData) => { // allData is an array of all the promise results
        return updateMessage(JSON.stringify(allData));
    });
}
```